# How should I display an uint8list in an JSON element?

Tags: json

I have to put an PDF in uint8list, that I already have, in JSON manually, for fake rest API.

I put it on string, like this:

```
  "matriculapdfuint8" : "37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 52, 10, 37, 226, 227, 207, 211, 10, 51, 32, 48, 32, 111, 98, 106, 10, 60, 60, 10, 47, 76, 101, 110, 103, 116, 104, 32, 52, 32, 48, 32, 111, 98, 106, 10, 47, 70, 105, 108, 116, 101, 114, 32, 47, 70, 108, 97, 116, 101, 68, 101, 99, 111, 100, 101, 10, 47, 76, 101, 110, 103, 116, 104, 32, 49, 48, 32, 48, 32, 111, 98, 106, 10, 47, 73, 110, 100, 105, 114, 101, 99, 116, 32, 91, 49, 32, 48, 32, 48, 32, 49, 32, 48, 32, 48, 93, 10, 47, 82, 111, 111, 116, 32, 49, 32, 48, 32, 48, 32, 65, 112, 112, 101, 110, 100, 32, 47, 80, 97, 103, 101, 115, 32, 49, 32, 48, 32, 48, 32, 82, 10, 47, 73, 110, 102, 111, 32, 50, 32, 48, 32, 82, 32, 10, 62, 62, 10, 115, 116, 114, 101, 97, 109, 10, 120, 95, 101, 110, 116, 114, 121, 10, 49, 54, 51, 10, 37, 69, 79, 70, 10, 10, 10, 69, 79, 70, 10",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "list" is a JSON *array*:

```
"matriculapdfuint8" : [37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 52, 10, 37, 226, 227, 207, 211, 10, 51, 32, 48, 32, 111, 98, 106, 10, 60, 60, 10, 47, 76, 101, 110, 103, 116, 104, 32, 52, 32, 48, 32, 111, 98, 106, 10, 47, 70, 105, 108, 116, 101, 114, 32, 47, 70, 108, 97, 116, 101, 68, 101, 99, 111, 100, 101, 10, 47, 76, 101, 110, 103, 116, 104, 32, 49, 48, 32, 48, 32, 111, 98, 106, 10, 47, 73, 110, 100, 105, 114, 101, 99, 116, 32, 91, 49, 32, 48, 32, 48, 32, 49, 32, 48, 32, 48, 93, 10, 47, 82, 111, 111, 116, 32, 49, 32, 48, 32, 48, 32, 65, 112, 112, 101, 110, 100, 32, 47, 80, 97, 103, 101, 115, 32, 49, 32, 48, 32, 48, 32, 82, 10, 47, 73, 110, 102, 111, 32, 50, 32, 48, 32, 82, 32, 10, 62, 62, 10, 115, 116, 114, 101, 97, 109, 10, 120, 95, 101, 110, 116, 114, 121, 10, 49, 54, 51, 10, 37, 69, 79, 70, 10, 10, 10, 69, 79, 70, 10]
```